# How to install git in magento 2.3.4?

Tags: magento2.3.4, git

I have problem in remove extension,

[image]

How to install git in magento 2?

Comment: do you have problem in remove extension or what?

Comment: I want to remove temando shipping extension,

Comment: if i remove i am getting the following error  https://snipboard.io/sBc1Jj.jpg

Comment: I installed the composer, but how to log in as user name password in Magento 2.

Comment: If i try to use composer remove command i am getting the following error  https://snipboard.io/DHhrQ8.jpg

Comment: The whole error means composer/git not connected with my credientials right?